# How to convert current view as camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

In 3D view i often find myself getting the perfect spot for the camera ,but Crtl alt 0 always ruins it,it always changes the view a lot,and trying to get the same angle by moving camera is also impossible and incredibly time conssuming.

How do i convert PERFECTLY any current view into an active camera?It's no big deal if it changes resolution(once again,align camera to current view is not what i am looking for since it do not replicate exactly the current view)

Comment: it should replicate the same view, maybe the Focal Lens of your Camera (available in Data > Lens is not the same as the Focal Lens of your 3D view (available in N menu > View > Lens

Comment: (data lense) I don't have a lense option for orthographic mode in Data >Lens ,only Orthographic scale but if litteraly change everything and " cut trough" my model i do have an option for the lense in perspective mode but my view in 3D view is not in perspective mode so adjusting both lense don't change my problem

Comment: If you switch to orthographic view in your 3D window you will have the same view as your orthographic camera, so it should also work. What do you mean when you say that it cuts through your model?

Comment: I should but i do not have the same view in ortoh for the camera and the current view ,the orthographic view camera goes very far for the model and distord the image like an exagerated fish eye effect,i can't move the camera in this view,just zoom, and when i zoom the camera cut through the model (the angle is so exagerated that it think part of my model is halfway in the camera. I cannot upload a blend file since it's sensible content, i have this problem with every work ,i find the perfect view in viewport and can't re-create it in camera view even with tweakings

Comment: Here is a topic where I created a script, that do this [Align camera to view precisely and automatically, without manual fiddling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107365/align-camera-to-view-precisely-and-automatically-without-manual-fiddling) and jubi made an addon http://zgodzinski.com/blender/Align%20Camera%20To%20View%20Auto.py

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner so I don't know perfectly but you can use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> then use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> then use the mouse and <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> in keyboard to change the position. It's very useful

Comment: even simpler, he can activate the Lock Camera to View in the N menu, so that when he's un camera view he can move exactly like the 3D view works

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> so you will have the point of view of your active camera. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> you will be able to move it like first person, then control your position with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> for go up and down if needed.