# how to get camera exactly like in the z perspective view

Tags: 3d-view, camera, axis

I'm making a text animation,in which in the end i want the camera to look exactly like when i look through the Z perspective view(numpad 7), so that the text seems 2d in the end.
how do i make the camera do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Top view for camera has no translation or rotation.**

See.

[Align camera to view precisely and automatically, without manual fiddling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107365/align-camera-to-view-precisely-and-automatically-without-manual-fiddling)

[How to convert current view as camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111195/how-to-convert-current-view-as-camera)

[image]
*Oops, realized after making gif q asked for perspective rather than ortho. *ie* don't change to ortho, however ortho is IMO may be a better way to make text look 2D.*

In the cameras property boxes, can clear both location and rotation, to have the camera facing downwards.

Via shortcuts / menu with

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>  *`Object > Clear > Clear Location`*

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>  *`Object > Clear > Clear Rotation`*

Then move up in $z$ and set camera type to perespective

Here is a script to do this, moving the camera to 2 bu directly above origin.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
cam = scene.camera

cam.matrix_world.identity()
cam.data.type = 'PERSP'
cam.matrix_world.translation.z = 2
```